# JSP Subdirectory problem -- Unable to compile the jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have created a website and hosted on windows and tomcat 6 .

The application could not detect the class files in WEB-INF->classes folder when we access the JSP file from the subdirectory.

I created a jsp file to just access a class file. The JSP is working fine when I access it from root folder. If i put the same jsp file in the  subdirectory, it is throwing errors saying

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an
>   internal error () that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   /test.jsp(8,0) The value for the
>   useBean class attribute
>   utils.LogWriter is invalid.
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1229)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1178)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3440)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:231)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

from logs extra info

> at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)

### example:

Test.jsp is not working in www.gamestest.com\community  but will work from www.gamestest.com

### code of test.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@ page import="java.util.Vector,utils.LogWriter"%>
<jsp:useBean id="logger" class="utils.LogWriter" />


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
        <div id="topmenu">
            <%@ include file="/../include/menu.jsp"%>
        </div>
</body>     
</html>
```

thanks
alex

Comment: The answer is in the Root Cause part of the stacktrace. Read the server logs. If you can't decipher them, update your question to include the entire stacktrace.

Comment: yes please add the entire stacktrace with relevant piece of code

Comment: There should be more into the stacktrace. Anyway, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024507/jasperexception-the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't have answer why it is not working when placed in sub directory, if it was working fine in root directory, but in line , why don't you try .