# The value for the useBean class attribute ****** is invalid

Tags: jsp, tomcat, javabeans

I use Tomcat 6 and have jsp file and java file which is located on the server
]
These are all files which I upload on the server

```
WEBINF/classes/layar/Testing.java
WEBINF/index.jsp
WEB-INF/lib/alt-rt.jar
WEB-INF/lib/charsets.jar
WEB-INF/lib/deploy.jar
WEB-INF/lib/dt.jar
WEB-INF/lib/javaws.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jce.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jconsole.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jspcontrols-rt.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jsse.jar
WEB-INF/lib/management-agent.jar
WEB-INF/lib/plugin.jar
WEB-INF/lib/resources.jar
WEB-INF/lib/rt.jar
WEB-INF/lib/sa-jdi.jar
WEB-INF/lib/tools.jar
```

Testing.java file

```
     package layar;

     import java.io.*;

      public class easyTesting 
      {
        public  void startCode()  
        {
         File f = new File("layertestnew.php");
          if(!f.exists())
          {
              f.createNewFile();
          }
          else 
          {
            f.delete();
          }
        }

        }
```

this is index.jsp file

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
      <html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Layer Easy testing</title>
      </head>
      <jsp:useBean id="link" class = "layar.Testing" />
      <body>
      <form action="poi.jsp" method="post">
      <INPUT type="button" value="Create script file" onClick = <%
  link.startCode(); %> "window.location.reload()"><br>
      <br>
      Select POIs type
      <div align="left"><br>
      <input type="radio" name="poi" value="1"  checked > dynamic<br>
      <input type="radio" name="poi" value="2">static<br>
       <input type="radio" name="poi" value="3"> both<br>

       <INPUT type="submit"  value="save"  ><br>

      </div>
      </form>
      </body>
      </html>
```

And when I open http://79.125.23.143:8080/lezv/index.jsp

I get the next error

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(9,0) The value for the useBean class   

     attribute layar.Testing is invalid.


    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
```

Comment: Does this class compile? Your `public class` name should be the same as the filename. you have called it `easyTesting`

Comment: Yes this class compiles. I changed the class name , now it's the same as the filename however I had error                      java.io.IOException: Permission denied
 java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
 java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:900)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JasperException: The value for the useBean class attribute is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024507/jasperexception-the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid)