# The value for the useBean class attribute beans.QueryBean is invalid

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I am having some trouble with java beans with jsp.

The error I'm getting is:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /runquery.jsp(16,3) The value for the useBean class attribute beans.QueryBean is invalid.

The beans classes are compiled and in myWebRoot/WEB-INF/classes/beans.

They have public default constructors and belong to the package 'beans'.

In the jsp file I have imported the bean classes and I'm using jsp:useBean:

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html" import="beans.*" %>
<snip...>
```

```
 <%-- load the bean with the input values --%>
 <jsp:useBean id="qi" class="beans.QueryBean" scope="request" />
 <jsp:setProperty name="qi" property="*" />
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

I've seen that this error means that the constructor of the class can't be called (here: [JasperException: The value for the useBean class attribute is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024507/jasperexception-the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid)), so the problem is either with the placement of the class files or a lack of default constructor.  I certainly have the default constructor so the only thing I can conclude is that my class files are not in the wrong place, but if this is the case, where do they go?

Comment: Maybe they're not entirely right compiled? Are you using an IDE or are you doing it by hand with javac? If IDE, which one? If javac, describe step by step how exactly you did it. By the way, that `@page import` is unnecessary. It applies to *scriptlets* only, not to `jsp:useBean`.

Comment: I compiled them with Eclipse originally, but that was not on the server I'm using, so I compiled again with javac (javac *.java) after removing all the preexisting class files. Is there a flag I should be using?