# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

I am using usebean tag on jsp but I am getting following error even though I have done my all best possible solution. can any one help The error is as follows

**type Exception report**

```
message /index.jsp (line: 1, column: 1) The value for the useBean     
class attribute org.deepak.my is invalid.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented 
it from fulfilling this request.
```

**exception**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: 1, column: 1) 
The value for the useBean class attribute org.deepak.my is invalid.
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:291)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:114)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1379)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1187)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2444)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:471)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3668)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:252)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17 logs.

Comment: How about posting a snip of the source JSP? It's hard to tell what might be the problem just looking at the stack trace.

Comment: didn't work for me.....!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **type** instead of **class** in below statement if there:- 
`<jsp:useBean id="my" class="org.deepak.my" />`

Try to find answer on SO before posting question, See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024916/5813861) given by @BalusC, it will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: look into the answer given by @BalusC , it will help you to find out possible reason.

Comment: try `<jsp:useBean id='my'> <jsp:attribute name="class" trim="true">org.deepak.my</jsp:attribute> </jsp:useBean> <% out.println(my.fun()); %>`