# WEB-INF doesn't contain the directory classes with .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, javabeans, tomcat9

When I run on tomcat server my java web application
eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ProvaUseBean2\WEB-INF doesn't contain the directory classes that must contain all the BeanClasses that I use in my index.jsp

[my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z57dN.png)

my index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<jsp:useBean id="classBean" scope="request" class="logic.bean.ClassBean"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

my ClassBean:

```
package logic.bean;

public class ClassBean {

    private String myAttr;
    
    public void setMyAttr(String s) {
        myAttr = s;
    }
    
    public String getMyAttr(String s) {
        return myAttr;
    }
}
```

When I run on TomcatServer I receive this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: [3], column: [0]) The value for the useBean class attribute [logic.bean.ClassBean] is invalid.
```

Comment: Check if this link is helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024507/jasperexception-the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid

Comment: The question is why at the runtime the ClassBean is not in WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Why is your web content inside of your Java source folder? They're not supposed to overlap.

Comment: Is it possible to work in this way?